# Can't push my Angular project to my github repo

Tags: github, windows-11

I'm trying to save my Angular project to a repo on github and am getting an error saying

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I found several posts on here helping people get their SSH keys setup which I also did successfully.  When I run `git commit -m "some message"` I get a response back saying there's nothing to commit and that the branch is clean.  I switched the origin back and forth from the `HTTPS` and `SSH` links with `git remote set-url origin (path)` to see if that would make a difference but still get the same error about having access rights when running `git push -u origin "main"`. I don't know what else to do or what I might be missing, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you created a remote repository to push to? https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github You need to create a remote and link to it with `git remote add origin  <REMOTE_URL>`

Comment: I created a new repository on github and followed the instructions displayed in the empty repo, is there something more we're supposed to do?

Comment: I just tried that and it says the remote origin already exists

Comment: Remove the `origin` remote and add it again if you say it exists already. `git remote rm origin`, then `git remote add origin <your github remote URL here>`. Then you might want to create a commit: `git add .` then `git commit -m "Initial commit"`. Finally `git push -u origin main`.

Comment: after you create the initial repo in github try to clone it in your pc and create you project inside that cloned repo and try the basic command to add all files and then push

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [`GitHub CLI gh`](https://cli.github.com/)

- [install it](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)
- authenticate yourself (using a [PAT - token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)) with [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)
  (double-check with [`gh auth status`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_status))
- create a new GitHub repository from your existing local repository with [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create)

Regarding the last point:

```bash
cd /path/to/repo
gh repo create my-project --private --source=. --push
```

Replace my-project by a new GitHub repository name (or delete your existing one first)

Everything will be initialized and pushed!